# /etc/network/interfaces: What's <eth>:<num> mean?

Tags: linux, networking

In `/etc/network/interfaces`, I have a physical eth0 and a vlan eth0.10, however there is an additional eth0:0

```
iface eth0 inet manual

iface eth0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth0

iface eth0:0 inet manual
```

What does a colon mean in interfaces file? Is it the same as a dot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is another network interface name. Linux accepts any string as the name of the network interface. `eth0` is one network interface. `eth1` is another. `eth0:0` is another network interface. `eth0!@#$&*()` may be another interface name. There is no special meaning in any `:` nor `.` nor any special characters in the interface name. [Allowed chars in Linux network interface names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451368/allowed-chars-in-linux-network-interface-names)

Well, maybe except for meaning/interpretation. I would expect the interface named `eth0:0` to be someone "binded"/"connected" with `eth0`. But that is (human) interpretation. I don't think linux binds any significance in how the network interface is named. For example, user [on this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447837/network-device-name-separators) uses `:` for ip aliases and `.` to denote VLAN.

In your configuration the three network interfaces `eth0`, `eth0.10` and `eth0:0` are all configured using manual configuration. Check the output of `cat /proc/net/dev` or any of `ip a` or `ifconfig` ip config utilities to see what network interfaces are available on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

Column in network interfaces mean virtual interface. Here is in Debian/Ubuntu:

```
[root@ubuntu ~]# cat /etc/network/interfaces
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 123.123.22.22
netmask 255.0.0.0
broadcast 123.255.255.255
```

For more info you can check [here](https://linuxconfig.org/configuring-virtual-network-interfaces-in-linux).

As far as I remember you can have up to 255 (or 256, not sure) virtual interfaces per physical one.